# Dynamic SQL query with JdbcCursorItemReader

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm using java configuration (spring-boot) for spring batch. I have a list of Employee Ids and for each Id, I need to run a query (like below) and then process the data.

```
select * from history where employee_id = ?
```

I understand we can use `reader.setPreparedStatementSetter` to dynamically set the parameter in the above SQL. However, I'm not sure how I can repeat the batch process for each of the employee id in the list. Even if I mark the reader() as @StepScope, the reader is called only once. (i.e.), the batch runs only once. Any help is appreciated.

```
    List employeeIds = new ArrayList();
    employeeIds.add(1);
    employeeIds.add(2);

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemReader<History> reader() {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<History> databaseReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        databaseReader.setSql("select * from history where employee_id = ?");
        databaseReader.setPreparedStatementSetter(..);
        ....

        return databaseReader;
    }


    @Bean
    public Step step(StepBuilder stepBuilder){
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("sample").
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer())
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: This is a common pattern (http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders). Your reader returns ID from the id-list and your current reader must be converted to a processor

Comment: Hmm, can one ItemReader be mapped to multiple ItemProcessors? Because, I want the ItemProcessor to run for every ID in the original list.

Comment: Yes, use a composite item processor (http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/CompositeItemProcessor.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first and foremost, I don't recommend you do this. In theory, and almost always in practice, opening a single cursor is FAR more efficient than querying separately for each time.

The "better" way would be to insert the ID list into a staging/driving table (typically in an earlier step, whenever you get that list of IDs from the original source) and then change your query to be something like:

```
select * from history where employee_id in (select id from driving_table)
```

---

Alternatively, you could, at a bare minimum, at least change your query to:

```
select * from history where employee_id in ( ? )
```

and pass in a list of IDs to it (be careful here as some databases limit the # of parameters in a query). If your list threatens to exceed that limit, you'd need to open a new cursor, effectively paginating over the list.

Comment: Thanks. The list contains about 200000 records - so "IN" wouldn't work. I could use JOIN instead.

Comment: Absolutely do the join. It will perform far better than pulling the data back just to query with it again and will reduce unnecessary I/O.